# How to get vertices of rotated Mesh in Libgdx without render?

Tags: java, android, rotation, libgdx, mesh

First I would like to know if it's possible to rotate a Mesh without drawing it.

If it is possible then how could I get the new vertices of the rotated mesh?

I need this to verify if a certain Mesh is still inside a rectangle after rotation and, I only want to draw it if it still's inside.